# Protecting class in a namespace

Tags: c#

Within a namespace I have a utility class that is only functional to a main class I'm exposing. How can I hide it away?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make your class **internal** and work with different assemblies or make it a **private nested** class of your main class.

```
public class A
{
  private class B { ... }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is only going to be used internally - within this "main class" - then it would seem most appropiate to nest it.

In other words, your structure would look like:

```
public class MainClass
{
    // ...

    private class NestedUtilityClass
    {
        // ... 
    }
}
```

This way, it's only accessible from *within `MainClass`*. You could change the modified of the nested class to be `protected` if you need it to be available in derived classes, of course.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Guillaume's and Noldorin's anwsers - if you'd like to have main class and utility class in different files - use partial. Mark your main class as partial and split it into 2 files - one containing main class implementation, other containing utility class.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use this class in one class, you can make it a private nested class:

```
public class MyPublicClass
{
    private class PrivateClass
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically within namespace your types can have either public or internal accessiblity. On the other hand nested types within classes can have private accessibility. As long as your utility type is only meaningful to your main class consider nesting utility class within main class with private accessibility.

Here is an excerpt from C# Specification:

> Non-nested types can have public or
>   internal declared accessibility and
>   have internal declared  accessibility
>   by default. Nested types can have
>   these forms of declared accessibility
>   too, plus one or more  additional
>   forms of declared accessibility,
>   depending on whether the containing
>   type is a class or struct:
>
> - A nested type that is declared in a class can have any of five forms of
>     declared accessibility (public, 
>     protected internal, protected,
>     internal, or private) and, like other
>     class members, defaults to  private
>     declared accessibility.
> - A nested type that is declared in a struct can have any of three forms of
>     declared accessibility (public, 
>     internal, or private) and, like other
>     struct members, defaults to private
>     declared accessibility.